# SIOD error while compiling festival with hts in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, text-to-speech, htk, festival

I tried to compile HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT on Ubuntu16.10.

```
/hts/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT$ ./configure --with-fest-search-path=$HOME/hts/festival/examples \
                                          --with-sptk-search-path=$HOME/hts/SPTK-3.10/bin \
                                          --with-hts-search-path=$HOME/hts/HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1/bin \
                                          --with-hts-engine-search-path=$HOME/hts/hts_engine_API-1.10/bin 

/hts/HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT$ make
```

However following error has occurred.

```
Extracting labels from utts/cmu_us_arctic_slt_a0001.utt
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : eof
Extracting labels from utts/cmu_us_arctic_slt_a0002.utt
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : eof
```

I assume that Festival caused these problem. This is my process for installing the Festival.

```
/hts/speech_tools$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/hts/speech_tools
/hts/speech_tools$ make
/hts/speech_tools$ make install
/hts/festival$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/hts/festival
/hts/festival$ make
/hts/festival$ make install
```

Could you assist me to solve this problem?

[add]

I get festival version 2.4 from (http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/2.4/)

Comment: You should have point your festival version then or where did you get it.

Comment: I get festival version 2.4  from [this site](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/2.4/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you have some old festival installed in your system as well, it should be some compatibility problem. By default "eof" symbol is not defined but it might remain in some old script. You can add the following line to init.scm in festival:

```
(set_backtrace 't)
```

then it will print stacktrace of the error and you'll be able to figure out why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile festival etc  with gcc 4.8

https://github.com/festvox/festival/issues/6